# ANGULAR - How to detect if HTML template changed?

Tags: angular

I am creating a custom modal window with dynamically calculated height depended on real inserted content.

It's easy to do it but pit hole is if in content is something hidden at the beginning. ( Typically if programmer insert element with *ngIf directive and they are simply NOT part of a calculation.

How can i detect if there are any changes in the DOM ? Thank you

Comment: Typically this situation is dealt with by using a min height property on your content pieces and a flexible container with auto overflow. Angular is not involved. Purely CSS and HTML.

Comment: Absolutely true but it is not as easy as it looks. I need to be sure than button bar will be always visible on the bottom of modal window. And if content + button bar is in total bigger than max-height of window then i want to create vertical scroolbar, but not on entire window but only on content - (button bar have to by visible always and not part of anything scrollable ) that is why i have to calculate the content height

Comment: You should look at using viewport units, namely `vh` for height calculations.

Comment: watch for div resize event, there are some libraries that can do this.

Answer (score -1):

use **lifecycle hook** in angular.

for more info on lifecycle hooks of angular go through this 
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks 
or more simple guide 
https://guide.freecodecamp.org/angular/lifecycle-hooks/

Comment: Hello Pravit, I am not sure this lifecycle hooks ( especially ngAfterViewInit() ) can fix my problem, because it's called just once and every time sooner than I need. The element under *ngIf directive can be inserted into DOM anytime and my component should be prepared for this without any code from outside.